# Different behaviour of comma operator in C++ with return?

Tags: c++, return, language-lawyer, operator-precedence, comma-operator

This (note the **comma operator**):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int x;
    x = 2, 3;
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

outputs **2**.

However, if you use `return` with the comma operator, this:

```
#include <iostream>
int f() { return 2, 3; }
int main() {
    int x;
    x = f();
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

outputs **3**.

Why is the comma operator behaving differently with `return`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Answer (score 147, accepted):

According to the [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) has lower precedence than `operator=`, so `x = 2,3;` is equivalent to `(x = 2),3;`. (Operator precedence determines how operator will be bound to its arguments, tighter or looser than other operators according to their precedences.)

Note the comma expression is `(x = 2),3` here, not `2,3`. `x = 2` is evaluated at first (and its side effects are completed), then the result is discarded, then `3` is evaluated (it does nothing in fact). That's why the value of `x` is `2`. Note that `3` is the result of the whole comma expression (i.e. `x = 2,3`), it won't be used to assign to `x`. (Change it to `x = (2,3);`, `x` will be assigned with `3`.)

For `return 2,3;`, the comma expression is `2,3`, `2` is evaluated then its result is discarded, and then `3` is evaluated and returned as the result of the whole comma expression, which is returned by the [return statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) later.

---

**Additional informations about [Expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) and [Statements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements)**

> An expression is a sequence of operators and their operands, that specifies a computation.

`x = 2,3;` is [expression statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Expression_statements), `x = 2,3` is the expression here.

> An expression followed by a semicolon is a statement.
>
> Syntax: `attr(optional) expression(optional) ;    (1)`

`return 2,3;` is [jump statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Jump_statements) ([return statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return)), `2,3` is the expression here.

> Syntax: `attr(optional) return expression(optional) ;     (1)`

Comment: good explanation. But are there some practical applications ? or just errors to be done?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre IMO it's just confusing, not useful at all.

Comment: I've seen it once or twice used in `for` loops when, bizarrely, it can make code *clearer* in numerical calculations.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 I tried to add more explanations, is it clear enough now?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: like Bathesheba says, it's so that you can write something like `i += 1, j += 2` in a for loop. Someone decided that the C++ grammar (or rather the C grammar, since this part was copied from there) is complicated enough already without trying to define that the precedence of comma is higher than assignment when you write `x = 2, 3` but lower when you write `x = 2, y = 3`!

Comment: @SteveJessop Precedence of comma is *lower* when you write `x = 2, 3`.   If comma had a higher precedence it would have been equivalent to `x = (2,  3)`, which would have meant `x = 3`.

Comment: @prakharsingh95: Yes, exactly. It would be difficult/complicated to make the precedence of comma higher just in that case, while retaining the useful fact that it's lower in the case of multiple assignments in a for loop separated by commas.

Comment: You could demonstrate this with `x = (2,3);`

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I’d say that the whole problem stems from the idea to treat the comma as an operator rather than a separator. Imagine what had happened if they had the idea of treating the semicolon as operator as well. How has the precedence to look like to make both `{ … ; … }` and `for(…;…;…) …; ` work as expected…

Comment: @Holger: Semicolon terminates a statement, it isn't an operator. This is something the answer could be tweaked to make more clear.

"x = 2 , 3" is an expression with 2 operators, and for reasons of supporting for(;;), = has higher precedence. (As everyone else said.)

But "return 2, 3;" is a statement that contains the expression "2, 3". There isn't *technically* a precedence to the keyword "return". (Although *effectively*, since it's part of the statement that accepts the expression, it is parsed last -- lower "precedence" than any operator *in* the expression.)

Comment: @Micha Berger: you didn’t get the point. The comma is an operator, because it was a deliberate decision of the C language designer that `,` is an operator. This causes `return 2 , 3` to be valid, without an actual purpose (talking about `C` without operator overloading). The desire to be able to write `x=4, y=5` rather than `x=4; y=5;` is only justified at two places, declarations and `for` loops. So look, e.g. at Java, where comma is not an operator, but just allowed to be used at declarations and `for` loops, the way you would expect it, without allowing these funny abuses ala `return 2, 3`.

Comment: @Holger: No, I got that. I was just saying the answer would do better if it made the difference between a statement and an expression more explicit. Then the comment chain wouldn't have the question about precedence of "," vs ";" -- since ";" terminates a statement -- and thus any expressions in it -- and is not part of the expression. Then you can talk about "(x=2), 3;" vs "return (2, 3);" in terms of "=" having a higher precedence verses a return statement taking an expression.

Comment: @MichaBerger You cannot treat return as an operator ever. Because then you could write `(return 3), y = 4;`, meaning, *return 3* , then *update y to 4*, which violates the obvious requirement that **return must be the last executed statement**. From what I understand, this is why `return <expr>` will **always** be `return (<expr>)`.

Comment: @prakharsingh95  - Thanks for the vehement agreement.

Comment: @MichaBerger I am always polite. No offense meant.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 -- I just meant there must have been a miscommunication. You repeated my point in a tone like you disagreed. To quote what I wrote, "Then you can talk about '(x=2), 3;' vs 'return (2, 3);' in terms of '=' having a higher precedence verses a return statement taking an expression." But in any case, when I wrote that the distinction wasn't yet in the answer. It was since added, so perhaps that's what threw you off.

Comment: @xyz, pointing out that you can actually put statements after a return, despite them not being able to be reached.

Answer (score 32):

The comma (also known as the *expression separation*) operator is evaluated from left to right. So `return 2,3;` is equivalent to `return 3;`.

The evaluation of `x = 2,3;` is `(x = 2), 3;` due to *operator precedence*. Evaluation is still from left to right, and the *entire* expression has the value 3 with the side-effect of `x` assuming the value of 2.

Comment: Can you please edit and elaborate more on *expression separation operator*? Like I mentioned in a comment on @songyuanyao's answer, I can understand why `return 2,3` and `return (2,3)` are the same. I believed the former should be `(return 2),3`.

Comment: @BiagioFesta explains that part well.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 `return 2` is a statement (like e.g. those formed by `for,while,if`), not an expression. You can't write e.g. `f(return 2)` or `2+return 2`. So, `(return 2),3` is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @chi Yes, you are correct. I meant I was expecting `return 2, 3` to be **interpreted** as `(return 2), 3`.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 You expected it to be interpreted as an invalid piece of program code?  :)

Comment: @Yakk no, I meant I expected it to return 2 and drop 3.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 expecting return 2, 3 to be interpreted as (return 2), 3 is expecting return (a statement) to be considered as an expression. Since return is a statement it could never be parsed in a way which would require it to be an expression.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 according to the grammar of C++, `return` can only occur in the following cases: (a) `return` *expression_opt* `;`, and (b) `return` *braced-init-list* `;` .

Answer (score 20):

This statement:

```
  x = 2,3;
```

is composed by two *expressions*:

```
> x = 2
> 3
```

Since [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence),
`=` has more precedence than comma `,`, so `x = 2` is evaluated and *after* `3`. Then `x` will be equal to `2`.

---

In the `return` instead:

```
int f(){ return 2,3; }
```

The language syntax is :

```
return <expression>
```

*Note* `return` is not part of expression.

So in that case the two expression will be evaluated will be:

```
> 2
> 3
```

But only the second (`3`) will be returned.

Comment: UV'd. Very picky, but would be nice if you marked `<expression>` as explicitly optional (from a grammar perspective).

Comment: There are 5 expressions in the parse tree of `x=2,3`. Both literals `2` and `3` are at the bottom of the parse tree, as is the identifier `x`. These are all individually valid expressions. Operator precedence means that `=` occurs _lower_ in the parse tree, and combines the two expressions `x` and `2` into the fourth expression `x=2`. Finally, the fifth expression is formed by the comma operator joining its two sides `x=2` and `3`. However, you incorrectly state that operator precedence determines the _order_ of evaluation. It doesn't. The order of evaluation is determined by sequencing rules.

Comment: I voted up for mentioning that return isn't part of an expression

Comment: @MSalters I agree with you, but I just incorrectly used the word "*because*", instead of "*since*". Something my English is not so perfect! ;-=

Comment: @BiagioFesta: Actually, _because_, _since_ and _so_ are all words which in English signal a causal relation. And leaving such words out might not be enough to stress that there is _no_ causal relation between two statements. Since we're often writing for inexperienced people here, we should be **explicit** when two statements are unrelated (i.e. in this case, we should be explicit that the precedence order is unrelated to the evaluation order)

Comment: Is "macro-expression" a technical term here? It seems a bit confusing to use it when "macro expressions" in the sense of preprocessor stuff also exist.

Answer (score 2):

Try to apply the simplistic approach just highlighting the precedence with parenthesis:

`( x = 2 ), 3;`

`return ( 2, 3 );`

Now we can see the binary operator "," working in the same way on both, from left to right.

Comment: The tricky part is realizing that the `x = 2, 3` is itself an expression ,while for `return` it's `return <expression>` . So you read them as `(x = 2, 3)` and `(2, 3)`.