# Incorrect result is shown using operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am performing complex addition & multiplication, the following code produces worng results despite correct formulation.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Complex{
    int real,img;
    public:

    Complex(int r=0,int i=0){
        real=r;
        img=i;
    }

    Complex operator + (Complex &);

    Complex operator * (Complex &);

    void print(){
        cout<<real<<" + "<<img<<"i"<<endl; 
    }
};

Complex Complex::operator + (Complex &c2){
    //checkig the variables true value
    cout<<real<<endl;
    cout<<c2.real<<endl;

    return(real+c2.real,img+c2.img);
}

Complex Complex::operator * (Complex &c2){
    return(real*c2.real-img*c2.img,real*c2.img+img*c2.real);
}

int main(){
    Complex c1(10,5), c2(2,4);
    Complex c3 = c1 + c2;
    c3.print();
    Complex c4 = c1 * c2;
    c4.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Actual results

```
9 + 0i
50 + 0i
```

Expected results

```
12 + 9i
0 + 50i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
return(real+c2.real,img+c2.img);
```

is **not** interpreted as

```
return Complex(real+c2.real,img+c2.img);
```

Due to the comma operator, it is effectively interpreted as:

```
int tmp = (real+c2.real, img+c2.img);
return Complex(tmp);
```

The comma operator makes the value of `tmp` to be equal to `img+c2.img`.

Effectively, that line translates to

```
return Complex(img+c2.img);
```

Hence, you get the wrong result.

You can change that line to

```
return {real+c2.real,img+c2.img};
```

Better yet, make it more readable and use

```
return Complex(real+c2.real,img+c2.img);
```

Update the second function appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting wrong output because you are not returning any Complex datatype.

You need to change `return(real+c2.real,img+c2.img);` into `return Complex(real+c2.real,img+c2.img);`

Same case for multiplication.

Comment: That worked , but why so? In general there is a type to a function it returns that type. Here why do i have to explicity return as Complex despite it being a Complex  type.

Comment: Because you are returning comma separated values. For example `return (A,B)` will actually return `B`. First element gets discarded first, then the second element is returned. You can [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364263/different-behaviour-of-comma-operator-in-c-with-return) this answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
return(real+c2.real,img+c2.img);
```

doesn't do what you think it does.

It's evaluating `real + c2.real, img + c2.img` using the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) and then passing the result of that expression to the constructor for Complex. That generates the results you're seeing where the imaginary value is 0 and the real value is the expected imaginary value - the calculated real value is being discarded and the calculated imaginary value is being passed to the Complex constructor.

You can fix this by writing

```
return {real+c2.real, img+c2.img};
```

which will do what you actually want