# right operand of comma operator has no effect -wunused variable

Tags: c++

While compiling simple cpp file I got an error. I want to write a function that changes celcius to farenheit.

```
double przelicznik(double n)
{
    n = 1,8 * n + 32;
    return n;
}
```

Also it doesn't give me a correct result.

Comment: It's `n = 1.8 * n + 32;`. The decimal separator is a dot `.` not a comma `,`.

Comment: You set `n=1`, then just calculate (and discard) `8 * n + 32`. As @jabaa mentioned it: use a `.` in `c++`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different behaviour of comma operator in C++ with return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364263/different-behaviour-of-comma-operator-in-c-with-return)

Comment: If you do want to use the `','` as the decimal (radix), you will need to set the proper `LOCALE` that uses the `','` for that purpose. Otherwise, you will need to use a period. It it was just a typo, then Ooops -- just change the `'','` to a `'.'` and your good.

Comment: To see the effect of the comma operator, try both `n = 1, 8 + 32;` and `n = (1, 8 + 32);` You will receive the `[-Wunused-value]` when compiling both, but the output will be very different -- why?

Comment: Wdavid are you claiming setting LOCALE changes which deckmal seperator C/C++ uses in source code?  Can you provide a link explaining?  I am unaware of such a language feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is.

```
  n = 1, (8 * n + 32)
```

The comma operator is a fairly uncommon mechanism where multiple expressions can be done in sequence.

correct code.

```
n = 1.8 * n + 32;
```

Comment: I suspect the user may actually be trying to use a `','` from his LOCALE without the LOCALE properly set (or it could just as easily be a typo...)

Comment: @David I don't think changing locale would have an effect on how C++ is parsed. You have to use `.`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `,` is an operator within the c++ language. Changing locale doesn't change how the compiler parses data. You may want to look at this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Comment: Thank you, silly me. I get used to comma to separate variable types in function, for example double varname(double, double), and i forgot that period is used for math.